# Hide Placeholder On Form Focus works only on one form

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a jQuery function which work to hide placeholder text on form focus, this functions works perfectly on the form in main page (Index.php), however it is not working on other forms which are designed using bootstrap (Members.php) as an example. I have tried to see where is the issue but it seems not working. I don't know if version incompatibility of both Bootstrap and jQuery caused this issue?!
I am using
- jquery-3.4.1.min.js
- bootstrap-3.3.7

=========================Backend.js=================================

```
// here is the jQuery function 
$(function(){
    'use strict';

    // Hide Placeholder On Form Focus
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function (){
        $(this).attr('data-text',$(this).attr('placeholder'));
        $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
    }).blur(function (){
        $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).attr('data-text'));
    });
});
```

==============================Index.php=====================================

```
// Here is the form where the jQuery function works fine      
<form class="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method = "POST">
    <h4 class="text-center">Admin Login</h4>
    <input class = "form-control input-lg" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class = "form-control input-lg"  type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password"/>
    <input class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

===============================Members.php===================================

```
// Function doesn't work on this form
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="?do=Insert" method="POST">
        <!-- start username field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required = "required" placeholder="Enter User Name" />    
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you not hide placeholders with CSS by coloring them in the background color of the input ?

Comment: I do want to learn jquery. I am also wondering why it’s not working on bootstrap form!

Comment: Is your `backend.js` included on both pages? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: It is actually on a separated folder while indexp.php and members.php are place in one folder

Comment: please check in the console if any error message you get.i tried your code with bootstrap and jquery version you mention it works for code you given for Members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = $("input");

input.focus(function(){
 $(this).attr("placeholder", " ")
});
input.blur(function(){
 $(this).attr("placeholder", "example")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="example">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation that shows why your code works.